# How to take off the outmost brace of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, I produce a list of matrices, likes `a=Table[IdentityMatrix[2], {i, 2}]`,so result is `{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}`.
But I want `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`, so what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`? If you paste it to the nb and try to evaluate it will tell you the syntax is not complete. What is the context? maybe you need `Apply` or `Sequence`?

Comment: I need to use these matrices as variables as a function. For instance, KroneckerProduct. If you type KroneckerProduct[a], where a={m1,m2}. That would be wrong. So you need to type KroneckerProduct[m1,m2], and get desirable result.

Comment: To continue with Kuba's comment, if you want to pass them as two arguments to a function you can use `Sequence @@ a`, for instance: `Plus[Sequence @@ a]`

Comment: Alternatively you can just write `{m1,m2} = Table[IdentityMatrix[2], {i, 2}]`

Comment: Kuba and KraZug, Thanks you, you have solved my problem.